# Css transition in quickly, out quickly

Tags: css

This seems really basic but I couldn't figure it out.  Is there a simple CSS only way to do cssa really quick fade in and a slow fade out.  This is for changing color on multiple divs.   About a .5 sec ease-in and a 2sec ease-out.

Thanks!

Comment: No code.. can't really be specific... set the transition times differently on the classes.

Comment: Trying out both.  Plus it makes me wait several minutes before I can mark one correct.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just change the `transition-duration` on the active state, for example:

```css
div {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  
  transition: all 5s;
}

div:hover {
  color: green;
  
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover over me to change the color</div>
```

Comment: That should work but will it do a  quick .5s transition out after 2s or will it be stretched out over 2s?  thx!

Comment: No, it will override the timing to `2s` if the element has an active class. I accidentally put `transition-delay` but it should be `transition-duration`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Thanks again!

Comment: couldn't get it to work.  Will keep playing with it tonight and update answer.  Thanks

Comment: @Fedreg I just added a better example. I exaggerated the fade out to illustrate it better. I always get the timing values wrong (my original answer had the durations swapped). Hope the Stack Snippet helps.

Comment: Thanks for updating that.  I did make that work off of your original example but this is clearer.  Appreciate the help!